# Conjunctive Normal Form vs Product of Sums

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I am confused as to what the difference between Conjunctive Normal Form and Product of Sums is.  Can someone explain what is different about them? It seems like they both only use groups of OR statements all AND'd together.

Thanks.

Comment: See in Wiki [Canonical normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form): "In *Boolean algebra*, any Boolean function can be put into the **(CDNF)** or minterm canonical form and its dual canonical conjunctive normal form (CCNF) or maxterm canonical form. [...] Two dual canonical forms of any Boolean function are a "sum of minterms" and a "product of maxterms." The term "Sum of Products" is widely used for the canonical form that is a disjunction (OR) of minterms. Its De Morgan dual is a "Product of Sums" or "PoS" for the canonical form that is a conjunction (AND) of maxterms."

Answer (score 1):

The CNF is a special type of POSE. We take max terms, which are negations and ORs of variables that evaluate to 1. We then AND the max-terms together. With a POSE, the terms don't have to be max-terms.